# Scala shapeless: how to convert a hlist.Mapper to a case class?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm brand new to shapeless and I would like to transform a `Mapper[mix.type, HNil]#Out` to a case class

How can I do this? (Let me know if you need more infos...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would only work if you define a case class that has the exact same *shape* that this `Mapper#Out`. If that's the case, you can create an instance of your case class using `shapeless.Generic`:

```
val mout = ... // HList coming from your Mapper
case class A(i: Int, s: String)
shapeless.Generic[A].from(mout): A
```

That's assuming `Generic#Repr` and `Mapper[mix.type, HNil]#Out` are the same type, which you can check using the following:

```
val mapper = the[Mapper[mix]]
val gen    = the[Generic[A]]
implicitly[mapper#Out =:= gen#Repr] // This only complies if scalac can
                                    // prove equality between these types
```

Comment: It works, thanks. (I had tried this but since IntelliJ saw it as an error I thought it wouldn't compile and didn't go further)